# Error while initializing storage in contract deployment

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, deploy

I am using folowing command:

`./tezos-client originate contract TestContract for tz1address transferring 1 from tz1address running contes.fi --init 'pair (map "KT1address" 1) (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00")'`

and get error:

`Ill typed data:
  1: (pair (map "KT1address" 1)
  2:       (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00"))
is not an expression of type pair (map address mutez) (map address timestamp)
From line 1 character 0 to line 2 character 71, value
  (pair (map "KT1address" 1)
        (map "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00"))
is invalid for type pair (map address mutez) (map address timestamp).
From line 1 character 0 to line 2 character 71,
unexpected type name pair, only a constant constructor can be used here.`

Please explain to me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Nobody can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Your error message describes the type you are failing to initialize properly: "is not an expression of type pair (map address mutez) (map address timestamp)".

First you need to specify each map with braces { }, and every element inside the braces begins with an Elt and is separated from other elements by a semi-colon. In your case you only have one element per map so you don't need any semi-colon.

You would use the following,

```
--init 'Pair { Elt "KT1address" 1 } { Elt "KT1address" "2019-06-09 00:00:00" }'
```

if you were initializing each map with 2 elements, it would look like,

```
--init 'Pair { Elt "KT1addressone" 1 ;  Elt "KT1addresstwo" 1} { Elt "KT1addressone" "2019-06-09 00:00:00" ; Elt "KT1addresstwo" "2019-06-09 00:00:00" }'
```